# Boundary conditions for symmetrical problem of truss

Tags: structural-analysis, finite-element-method

What is the symmetrical problem for this truss, specifically the upper right part of it. What boundary conditions have to be added (i.e. supports).
What confused me was the specification for the upper right part. I understand that one quarter of the model is enough as there is symmetry in both x and y axis.
There are masses on nodes 2 and 4. Pin support on nodes 1 and 3

[image: truss]

Comment: What is the truss intended for, and what are you trying to solve for?

Comment: Is that a spring in the middle?  A truss by definition moves as a singe unit.  If 1 and 3 are supports that prevent lateral movement, they are all you need.

Comment: I thought it was an electric circuit with a resistor in the middle at first glance.